# Internet Explorer Open New Tab Showing Downloads

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, internet-explorer-10, selenium-iedriver

I'm using Selenium for a web automation task that would download files and only close the web driver when the downloads have finished. I have implemented a way to scan the downloads in progress for Chrome and Firefox by opening a new tab, going to their respective downloads manager URLs and finding web elements of all the downloads of the current web driver instance. For Chrome the downloads manager URL is: 'chrome://downloads/' and for Firefox: 'about:downloads'.

Is there a similar way I can do this for Internet Explorer? The only downloads list I've seen for IE is a separate window which I cannot access with Selenium.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this will work for **all** downloads, but here is the idea:

1. Read the content of the folder where the downloads are stored
2. If the file size is zero 0kb, the download is still in progress.

Tested with a 5GB file on http://www.engineerhammad.com/2015/04/Download-Test-Files.html

[image]
[image]

Comment: The reason why I don't want to use the approach of looking at file sizes is because the files can't be traced back to the web driver instance. If 2 web automation tasks are running simultaneously and one instance is downloading a larger file than the other, they need to be handled separately.